# .every() only accounts for the last element in the array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an array of objects inside of objects and return the available desks based on the startTime and endTime supplied. Every desk holds bookings which shouldn't overlap with the supplied start and end time. However, when I loop through it, the code only returns a desk if the last desk in the array does not clash with the supplied data. If the it clashes with the last element it returns undefined.

```
const org = {
  id: '123',
  name: 'apple',
  numofDesks: 12,
  desks: [
    {
      deskID: '1',
      bookings: [
        {
          id: '123',
         date: {
            day: 14,
            month: 02,
            year: 1999,
          },
          startTime: 14,
          finishTime: 16,
        },
        {
          id: '123',
          date: {
            day: 14,
            month: 02,
            year: 1999,
          },
          startTime: 17,
          finishTime: 20,
        },
      ],
      deskID: '2',
      bookings: [
        {
          id: '123',
          date: {
            day: 14,
            month: 02,
            year: 1999,
          },
          startTime: 11,
          finishTime: 12,
        },
        {
          id: '123',
          date: {
            day: 14,
            month: 02,
            year: 1999,
          },
          startTime: 8,
          finishTime: 10,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const booking = {
 startTime: 8,
 finishTime: 11,
};

const avaliableDesks = org.desks.find(({ bookings }) =>
  bookings.every(
    ({ startTime, finishTime }) =>
      //checks if the start&end times overlap with the existing booking 
      !(booking.startTime <= finishTime && startTime <= booking.finishTime),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Where is `booking` defined and what is its value?

Comment: You could use `filter` to return all the desks that match the condition (instead of `find`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: the `desks` array contains just one object. but this object has assigned twice `deskId` and `bookings ` ... I assume the object structure is not correct.

Comment: ^ this. There is a `], [` missing! So it's not that the code works only if the _last_ element is OK, but if the _only_ element is OK, since there is only one (which has the values of the second definition because defining a property with the same name twice will use the last value)!

Comment: @PeterSeliger thank you. I've spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out...

Comment: @AlekasndrKataev ... you are welcome and you might consider deleting your Q. unless there is another unsolved/unsolvable problem with your code.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I am trying, for some reason it won't let me. It says: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it

Comment: Also, `org` seems like an object for only one type of class - ok if that's the intention = you'll need an array of `org` objects for different classes.

Comment: Also, why are you repeating `id:"123"`?  the whole `org` is "123"...

Comment: Also, `numofDesks` is unnecessary:  just use `org.desks.length`.

Comment: Also, poorly constructed array of object: you need to add `},{` just before `deskID:"2"` - not only it will separate the objects in the array, but `deskID:"1"` will not be overridden. It also overrides the `bookings` array...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of your logic with start and finish times...
And, using `<=` (or `>=`) is not practical: it takes (some) time to leave desk (and classroom) before it can be available for the next student...  At the very least (if you don't want to add some, say, 15 minutes, buffer) - don't use the `=` part.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#filter` is the method you want, not `Array#find`.

```
const avaliableDesks = org.desks.filter(({ bookings }) =>
  bookings.every(
    ({ startTime, finishTime }) =>
      //checks if the start&end times overlap with the existing booking
      !(booking.startTime <= finishTime && startTime <= booking.finishTime),
  ),
);
```

Comment: `filter` can return more than one result, yes, but if it had been just this problem then wouldn't have `find` worked as well? I would have expected a result other than `undefined` with `find` as well...